# How to get full debug list for insecure warning in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, https, insecure-connection

I've scoured the web (and here) but still can't find detailed information on how to properly debug a website in which Chrome reports is insecure.

- no http/https errors in the browser console
- used dev tools to find
- http: function to prove not exists    cleared browser cache    tried
- incognito mode    other browsers report secure

Everything I've read about this exact scenario eventually fixes itself with time.  This is not professional to just wait.

I'm simply looking for a way to see exactly what Chrome thinks is insecure so I can fix it. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer.  There is an initially hidden "Security" tab in dev tools that lists all errors Chrome sees.

All I had to do was click the 3 vertical dots in the upper right corner of dev tools and choose "More Tools" submenu and then "Security".